# Perlbrew cannot run simple scripts IPC::System::Simple required for Fatalised/autodying system()

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I am a new perlbrew user, as I wish to upgrade to perl 5.30.0 on Ubuntu.

I have done

```
perlbrew init
perlbrew install perl-5.30.0
perlbrew switch perl-5.30.0
```

so I try to run this test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
```

but this gives the long error

```
IPC::System::Simple required for Fatalised/autodying system() at /home/con/Scripts/say.pl line 6.
    main::BEGIN() called at /home/con/Scripts/say.pl line 6
    eval {...} called at /home/con/Scripts/say.pl line 6
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/con/Scripts/say.pl line 6.
Command exited with non-zero status 2
```

I thought that libraries (especially standard ones) were supposed to be loaded automatically via perlbrew? How can I get this simple script to run?

Comment: Very curious. I get the same on perlbrew managed v5.29.2 (which otherwise works as expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, according to @ikegami, and that worked for me: `/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perl -e'use IPC::System::Simple'; /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/cpan IPC::System::Simple; /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perl -e'use IPC::System::Simple'`

of course, for anyone in the future, this will be slightly different for you, as your directories may be set differently, and username isn't `con`

Answer (score 2):

From [autodie](https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) we see that it's documented behavior

> If `system` is specified as an argument to `autodie`, then it uses
>      `IPC::System::Simple` to do the heavy lifting. See the description of that
>      module for more information.

So one does need [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple) installed for `:all` tag (which implies `system`).

It strikes me as curious that a core functionality requires a non-core module, and quietly too (doesn't complain at installation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting exactly the same error on a non-perlbrew Perl. It seems [autodie](http://p3rl.org/autodie) requires [IPC::System::Simple](http://p3rl.org/IPC::System::Simple) when running under fatal warnings or with `:all`, but it doesn't require it during installation.

See also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1183231.

Comment: so how should I alter my script so I can `use autodie ':all'`?

Comment: Add `use IPC::System::Simple` and install it for all the perls you need to run the script in.

Comment: (don't need `use IPC::System::Simple;` in order for `autodie` to work with `:all`, just that the module is on the system)

Comment: `cpanm` says that ` IPC::System::Simple` is already installed, but perlbrew cannot find it :(

Comment: @con, Re "*`cpanm` says that ` IPC::System::Simple` is already installed*", You are presumably using the wrong `cpanm`. You need to use the one installed by the `perl` for which you want to install modules. You probably didn't install one with the `perl` in question, and it's picking up another one in your path. Why complicate things by using `cpanm`? Just use `cpan IPC::System::Simple`.

Comment: @ikegami unfortunately installing installing with `cpanm` still gives the same error :( even when I do the installation inside the perlbrew shell :( it's all up to date with version 1.25

Comment: @con I've had similar trouble due to `local::lib` (and/or `PERL5LIB`)

Comment: Please provide the output of `which cpan; head -1 "$( which cpan )"; which perl; perl -le'print "$_=$ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV;'`

Comment: @ikegami in normal shell `/usr/bin/cpan
#!/usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl` & perlbrew `/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/cpan
#!/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perl
/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perl
PERL5LIB=
PERLBREW_LIB=
PERLBREW_MANPATH=/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/man
PERLBREW_PATH=/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin
PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.30.0
PERLBREW_ROOT=/home/con/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_SKIP_INIT=1
PERLBREW_VERSION=0.86
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=`

Comment: One more: `/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perl -e'use IPC::System::Simple'; /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/cpan IPC::System::Simple; /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perl -e'use IPC::System::Simple'`

Comment: (I do have two things for you to change, but I'll wait for this answer first)